# Unable to delete and insert M-M relational data using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, many-to-many, dbcontext

I have M-M relational data structure as follows. But, I cannot able to delete and insert the record. I have googled and use the samples from [Link1](https://practiceaspnet.wordpress.com/tag/crud-in-many-to-many-relationships/) and [Link2](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/update-many-to-many-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx)

**Company:**

```
[Serializable]
public class Company : Base.BaseEntity
{
    public long CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string TimeZone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public long? CityId { get; set; }
    public long? StateId { get; set; }
    public int Zip { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string FederalEin { get; set; }
    public string WebPage { get; set; }
    public string StateEmployerNumber { get; set; }
    public long? AdministratorId { get; set; }
    public string OfflineAdlLockoutTime { get; set; }
    public bool? IsAllowWindowsAuthentication { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CommunityType> CommunityTypeList { get; set; }
}
```

**Community Type:**

```
[Serializable]
public class CommunityType : Base.BaseEntity 
{
    public long CommunityTypeId { get; set; }
    public string CommunityTypeName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Company> CompanyList { get; set; }
}
```

And, I have a repo method as

**CompanyRepository**

```
public void Persist(Company entity)
{
    using (var dbContext = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IDbContext>())
    {
        // Here I am going to save the company information (may be edited some properties).
        dbContext.Persist(entity, entity.CompanyId);
        dbContext.SaveChanges(entity.CompanyId);

        // Here I am trying to delete the existing community types and insert a new community types.
        var existingCompany = dbContext.Table<Company>().Include(i => i.CommunityTypeList).AsNoTracking().Where(s => s.CompanyId == entity.CompanyId).FirstOrDefault();
        var deletedCommunityTypes = existingCompany.CommunityTypeList.Except(entity.CommunityTypeList, x => x.CommunityTypeId).ToList();
        var addedCommunityTypes = entity.CommunityTypeList.Except(existingCompany.CommunityTypeList, x => x.CommunityTypeId).ToList();
        deletedCommunityTypes.ForEach(c => existingCompany.CommunityTypeList.Remove(c));

        foreach (var c in addedCommunityTypes)
        {
            existingCompany.CommunityTypeList.Add(c);
        }

        dbContext.Persist(existingCompany, existingCompany.CompanyId);
        dbContext.SaveChanges(existingCompany.CompanyId);
    }
}
```

And my DB Context method as

```
public void Persist<TEntity>(TEntity entity, long id, bool isHardDelete = false) where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    try
    {
        if (!isHardDelete)
        {
            var item = entity as BaseEntity;
            if (id <= 0)
            {
                Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
                Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
            }
            else
            {
                Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity); // I have an error here
                Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
        }
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
    {
        throw new Exception(GetFullErrorText(dbEx), dbEx);
    }
}

public int SaveChanges(long id = 0)
{
    try
    {
        ChangeTracker.Entries().ForEach(entity =>
        {
            var baseDto = entity.Entity as BaseEntity;
            if (baseDto == null) return;
            if (id <= 0)
            {
                baseDto.CreatedOn = baseDto.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                baseDto.CreatedBy = baseDto.UpdatedBy = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                baseDto.UpdatedBy = 1;
                baseDto.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
            }
        });
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
    {
        throw new Exception(GetFullErrorText(dbEx), dbEx);
    }
}
```

I have a below error when attach the entity.

> Attaching an entity of type 'RDS.Models.Entities.Masters.Company'
>   failed because another entity of the same type already has the same
>   primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or
>   setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any
>   entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because
>   some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key
>   values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state
>   to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to
>   'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

Comment: If the entity you are passing into your method `Persist()` is retrieved by a db call, for example `var entitiy = db.Thingy.First(pred)`, then unless you have set `AsNoTracking()` it is already attached to the context and you need not attach again?

Comment: @Wurd I have used `AsNoTracking()` as well. But, no luck

Comment: Do changes get saved on the entity when you don't include the `Attach()`?

Comment: @Wurd I can't get you.